# How to modify float value in python dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The python service gets the data in the following json format:

```
{
"total" : 3,
"records" : [ 
  {
    "regdId" : "A-10",
    "firstName" : "Adam",
    "amt" : 20
  }, 
 {
    "regdId" : "A-11",
    "firstName" : "Beth",
    "amt" : 22
 },
 {
    "regdId" : "A-12",
    "firstName" : "Candy",
    "amt" : 20.92
 }
]
}
```

Within python, the logic is like:

```
a = json.loads(file.text)
print(a)
```

This prints:

> { "total" : 2, "records" : [  { "regdId" : "A-10", "firstName" :
> "Adam", "amt" : 20 }, { "regdId" : "A-11", "firstName" : "Beth",
> "amt" : 22 }, { "regdId" : "A-12", "firstName" : "Candy", "amt" :
> 20.92 } }

The value of "amt" gets printed as it is. Need a logic to include in the python code, so that, the value of "amt" gets formatted to 2 digits after a decimal point? 2 trailing 0s for example.

Requirement is that, the value should have 2 0s after decimal point. In cases where there are 2 digits after decimal, they should be as they are.

With a simple variable, this can be done by:

```
a = 12
format(a,'.2f')
```

How to implement the above in a dictionary?

Comment: what your attempt at this with dicts ?, is it only amount that has to be converted to two decimal floats ?

Comment: Yes, only the amt.

Comment: @layman, eventually (after loading json from text), you'll get strings like `'3.00', 20.00' ...` - is that what you need?

Comment: The answers provided have resolved the issue. thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for index in range(len(data['records'])):
   data['records'][index]['amt'] = format(data['records'][index]['amt'],'.2f')
```

data here is above json

Comment: This will change the actual value in the dict to a string which is not necessarily wanted...

Comment: well then make a copy https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/copy

Comment: You can iterate over `data["records"]` directly to avoid this nested indexing. `for r in  data["records"]: r['amt'] = format(r['amt'], '.2f')`.